# There was an error while trying to load the gem 'textris'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am trying to use textris on my rails app. But I got `"There was an error while trying to load the gem 'textris'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)"` error.

I followed the tutorial from Textris gem official page [here](https://github.com/visualitypl/textris).

This is the full error:

```
Colins-MacBook-Pro:rentlord Ryzal$ rails s
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:80:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require': There was an error while trying to load the gem 'textris'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `require'
    from /Users/Ryzal/Desktop/Sites/rentlord/config/application.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Any help? Thanks!

============================= UPDATE ==============================

**Here is my Gemfile.lock:**

```
GIT
  remote: git://github.com/Compass/compass-rails.git
  revision: 62e37c73e8c8470b094e8d7f2cbb98356b591e57
  branch: master
  specs:
    compass-rails (3.0.2)
      compass (~> 1.0.0)
      sass-rails (< 5.1)
      sprockets (< 4.0)

GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (4.2.3)
      actionpack (= 4.2.3)
      actionview (= 4.2.3)
      activejob (= 4.2.3)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
    actionpack (4.2.3)
      actionview (= 4.2.3)
      activesupport (= 4.2.3)
      rack (~> 1.6)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    actionview (4.2.3)
      activesupport (= 4.2.3)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    activejob (4.2.3)
      activesupport (= 4.2.3)
      globalid (>= 0.3.0)
    activemodel (4.2.3)
      activesupport (= 4.2.3)
      builder (~> 3.1)
    activerecord (4.2.3)
      activemodel (= 4.2.3)
      activesupport (= 4.2.3)
      arel (~> 6.0)
    activesupport (4.2.3)
      i18n (~> 0.7)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      thread_safe (~> 0.3, >= 0.3.4)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    arel (6.0.3)
    autoprefixer-rails (6.3.3.1)
      execjs
    bcrypt (3.1.11)
    bcrypt (3.1.11-x86-mingw32)
    better_errors (2.1.1)
      coderay (>= 1.0.0)
      erubis (>= 2.6.6)
      rack (>= 0.9.0)
    binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
      debug_inspector (>= 0.0.1)
    bootstrap-sass (3.3.4.1)
      autoprefixer-rails (>= 5.0.0.1)
      sass (>= 3.2.19)
    builder (3.2.2)
    byebug (8.2.2)
    capistrano (3.4.0)
      i18n
      rake (>= 10.0.0)
      sshkit (~> 1.3)
    capistrano-bundler (1.1.4)
      capistrano (~> 3.1)
      sshkit (~> 1.2)
    capistrano-rails (1.1.6)
      capistrano (~> 3.1)
      capistrano-bundler (~> 1.1)
    capistrano-rvm (0.1.2)
      capistrano (~> 3.0)
      sshkit (~> 1.2)
    capistrano3-puma (1.2.1)
      capistrano (~> 3.0)
      puma (>= 2.6)
    carrierwave (0.10.0)
      activemodel (>= 3.2.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.2.0)
      json (>= 1.7)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
    celluloid (0.17.3)
      celluloid-essentials
      celluloid-extras
      celluloid-fsm
      celluloid-pool
      celluloid-supervision
      timers (>= 4.1.1)
    celluloid-essentials (0.20.5)
      timers (>= 4.1.1)
    celluloid-extras (0.20.5)
      timers (>= 4.1.1)
    celluloid-fsm (0.20.5)
      timers (>= 4.1.1)
    celluloid-pool (0.20.5)
      timers (>= 4.1.1)
    celluloid-supervision (0.20.5)
      timers (>= 4.1.1)
    choice (0.2.0)
    chronic (0.10.2)
    chunky_png (1.3.5)
    coderay (1.1.1)
    coffee-rails (4.1.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.1.x)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.10.0)
    compass (1.0.3)
      chunky_png (~> 1.2)
      compass-core (~> 1.0.2)
      compass-import-once (~> 1.0.5)
      rb-fsevent (>= 0.9.3)
      rb-inotify (>= 0.9)
      sass (>= 3.3.13, < 3.5)
    compass-core (1.0.3)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      sass (>= 3.3.0, < 3.5)
    compass-import-once (1.0.5)
      sass (>= 3.2, < 3.5)
    concurrent-ruby (1.0.1)
    connection_pool (2.2.0)
    daemons (1.2.3)
    debug_inspector (0.0.2)
    delayed_job (4.1.1)
      activesupport (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
    delayed_job_active_record (4.1.0)
      activerecord (>= 3.0, < 5)
      delayed_job (>= 3.0, < 5)
    devise (3.5.6)
      bcrypt (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 3.2.6, < 5)
      responders
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    email_reply_parser (0.5.8)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    eventmachine (1.0.9.1)
    excon (0.48.0)
    execjs (2.6.0)
    ffi (1.9.10)
    ffi (1.9.10-x86-mingw32)
    fog-aws (0.9.1)
      fog-core (~> 1.27)
      fog-json (~> 1.0)
      fog-xml (~> 0.1)
      ipaddress (~> 0.8)
    fog-core (1.36.0)
      builder
      excon (~> 0.45)
      formatador (~> 0.2)
    fog-json (1.0.2)
      fog-core (~> 1.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.10)
    fog-xml (0.1.2)
      fog-core
      nokogiri (~> 1.5, >= 1.5.11)
    font-awesome-rails (4.5.0.1)
      railties (>= 3.2, < 5.1)
    formatador (0.2.5)
    globalid (0.3.6)
      activesupport (>= 4.1.0)
    griddler (1.3.0)
      htmlentities
      rails (>= 3.2.0)
    haml (4.0.7)
      tilt
    hitimes (1.2.3)
    hitimes (1.2.3-x86-mingw32)
    htmlentities (4.3.4)
    i18n (0.7.0)
    ipaddress (0.8.3)
    jbuilder (2.4.1)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0, < 5.1)
      multi_json (~> 1.2)
    jquery-rails (4.1.0)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    jquery-ui-rails (5.0.5)
      railties (>= 3.2.16)
    json (1.8.3)
    jwt (1.5.3)
    kaminari (0.16.3)
      actionpack (>= 3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    libv8 (3.16.14.13)
    listen (2.9.0)
      celluloid (>= 0.15.2)
      rb-fsevent (>= 0.9.3)
      rb-inotify (>= 0.9)
    loofah (2.0.3)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.6.3)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 3)
    mail_extract (0.1.4)
    maildir (2.2.1)
    mailman (0.7.3)
      activesupport (>= 2.3.4)
      i18n (>= 0.4.1)
      listen (~> 2.2)
      mail (>= 2.0.3)
      maildir (>= 0.5.0)
    mime-types (2.99.1)
    mini_portile2 (2.0.0)
    minitest (5.8.4)
    multi_json (1.11.2)
    mysql2 (0.3.20)
    mysql2 (0.3.20-x86-mingw32)
    nested_form (0.3.2)
    net-scp (1.2.1)
      net-ssh (>= 2.6.5)
    net-ssh (3.0.2)
    nokogiri (1.6.7.2)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.0.0.rc2)
    nokogiri (1.6.7.2-x86-mingw32)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.0.0.rc2)
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    phony (2.15.18)
    postmark (1.7.1)
      json
      rake
    postmark-rails (0.5.2)
      actionmailer (>= 3.0.0)
      postmark (~> 1.0)
    puma (3.1.0)
    rack (1.6.4)
    rack-pjax (0.8.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.5)
      rack (~> 1.1)
    rack-test (0.6.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.2.3)
      actionmailer (= 4.2.3)
      actionpack (= 4.2.3)
      actionview (= 4.2.3)
      activejob (= 4.2.3)
      activemodel (= 4.2.3)
      activerecord (= 4.2.3)
      activesupport (= 4.2.3)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.2.3)
      sprockets-rails
    rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.alpha)
    rails-dom-testing (1.0.7)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.beta, < 5.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6.0)
      rails-deprecated_sanitizer (>= 1.0.1)
    rails-erd (1.4.6)
      activerecord (>= 3.2)
      activesupport (>= 3.2)
      choice (~> 0.2.0)
      ruby-graphviz (~> 1.2)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.3)
      loofah (~> 2.0)
    rails_12factor (0.0.2)
      rails_serve_static_assets
      rails_stdout_logging
    rails_admin (0.6.8)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      coffee-rails (~> 4.0)
      font-awesome-rails (>= 3.0, < 5)
      haml (~> 4.0)
      jquery-rails (>= 3.0, < 5)
      jquery-ui-rails (~> 5.0)
      kaminari (~> 0.14)
      nested_form (~> 0.3)
      rack-pjax (~> 0.7)
      rails (~> 4.0)
      remotipart (~> 1.0)
      safe_yaml (~> 1.0)
      sass-rails (>= 4.0, < 6)
    rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.5)
    rails_stdout_logging (0.0.4)
    railties (4.2.3)
      actionpack (= 4.2.3)
      activesupport (= 4.2.3)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (11.0.1)
    rb-fsevent (0.9.7)
    rb-inotify (0.9.7)
      ffi (>= 0.5.0)
    rdoc (4.2.2)
      json (~> 1.4)
    redis (3.2.2)
    ref (2.0.0)
    remotipart (1.2.1)
    render_anywhere (0.0.12)
      rails (>= 3.0.7)
    responders (2.1.1)
      railties (>= 4.2.0, < 5.1)
    ruby-graphviz (1.2.2)
    rvm1-capistrano3 (1.4.0)
      capistrano (~> 3.0)
      sshkit (>= 1.2)
    safe_yaml (1.0.4)
    sass (3.4.21)
    sass-rails (5.0.4)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (>= 1.1, < 3)
    sdoc (0.4.1)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      rdoc (~> 4.0)
    sidekiq (4.1.1)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      connection_pool (~> 2.2, >= 2.2.0)
      redis (~> 3.2, >= 3.2.1)
    sprockets (3.5.2)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.0.4)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    sshkit (1.8.1)
      net-scp (>= 1.1.2)
      net-ssh (>= 2.8.0)
    sucker_punch (2.0.1)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0.0)
    textris (0.4.1)
      actionmailer (~> 4.0)
      activejob (~> 4.2)
      activesupport (~> 4.2)
      phony (~> 2.8)
      render_anywhere (~> 0.0)
    therubyracer (0.12.2)
      libv8 (~> 3.16.14.0)
      ref
    thin (1.6.4)
      daemons (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.9)
      eventmachine (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.4)
      rack (~> 1.0)
    thor (0.19.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.5)
    tilt (2.0.2)
    timers (4.1.1)
      hitimes
    turbolinks (2.5.3)
      coffee-rails
    twilio-ruby (4.11.1)
      builder (>= 2.1.2)
      jwt (~> 1.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.3.0)
    tzinfo (1.2.2)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    tzinfo-data (1.2016.1)
      tzinfo (>= 1.0.0)
    uglifier (2.7.2)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      json (>= 1.8.0)
    warden (1.2.6)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    web-console (2.3.0)
      activemodel (>= 4.0)
      binding_of_caller (>= 0.7.2)
      railties (>= 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
    whenever (0.9.4)
      chronic (>= 0.6.3)

PLATFORMS
  ruby
  x86-mingw32

DEPENDENCIES
  better_errors
  bootstrap-sass (~> 3.3.4.1)
  byebug
  capistrano
  capistrano-bundler
  capistrano-rails
  capistrano-rvm
  capistrano3-puma
  carrierwave
  coffee-rails (~> 4.1.0)
  compass-rails!
  daemons (~> 1.2, >= 1.2.3)
  delayed_job_active_record
  devise
  email_reply_parser (~> 0.5.8)
  execjs
  fog-aws
  griddler
  jbuilder (~> 2.0)
  jquery-rails
  jquery-ui-rails
  mail_extract (~> 0.1.4)
  mailman
  mysql2 (~> 0.3.18)
  postmark-rails (~> 0.5.2)
  puma (= 3.1.0)
  rails (= 4.2.3)
  rails-erd
  rails_12factor (= 0.0.2)
  rails_admin (~> 0.6.8)
  rvm1-capistrano3
  sass-rails (~> 5.0)
  sdoc (~> 0.4.0)
  sidekiq
  sucker_punch (~> 2.0, >= 2.0.1)
  textris (~> 0.4.1)
  therubyracer
  thin
  turbolinks
  twilio-ruby
  tzinfo-data
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
  web-console (~> 2.0)
  whenever (~> 0.9.4)

BUNDLED WITH
   1.11.2
```

Comment: Did you remember to run `bundle install`?

Comment: Yeah, I have run that

Comment: What if you run the server using `bundle exec rails s`?

Comment: I got the same error :(

Comment: What happens if you go into irb and run `require 'textris'`?

Comment: I got `NoMethodError: private method 'include' called for Textris::Message:Class`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106665/discussion-between-shelvacu-and-ryzalyusoff).

Comment: can you provide details about your Gemfile.lock ?

Comment: @AbdooDev hey, i've added my Gemfile.lock on my update above